Как мне создать переменную такого же типа C#?
у меня есть небольшая иерархия классов:
class Item {
    int count;
}

class UsableItem : Item {
    public void OnUse() {}
}

class ComponentItem : Item {}

и есть массив (инвентарь), содержащий различные объекты типов UsableItem и ComponentItem, т.е. разные.
List<Item> inventory;

Я хочу перенести определённое кол-во предметов из одного инвентаря в другой
int item_count = 22;
int item_index = 3;

inventory_from[item_index].count -= item_count

// И вот тут мне нужно создать объект такого же класса
// как и inventory_from[item_index] и засунуть в другой инвентарь

Как мне это сделать?

У вас есть типы, реализации типов, экземпляры типов. У вас объекты, на объекты есть ссылки. Массив объектов - это массив ссылок на объекты. Что бы "перетащить" объекты откуда то куда то - перетащите ссылки на эти объекты. У вас должно быть два массива ссылок на объекты. Скопируйте нужные ссылки на объекты из массива в массив, в первом массиве обнулите ссылки, или пересоберите массив. У вас контейнер List. Скопируйте что нужно из одного листа в другой лист - скопируются ссылки на объекты. В первом листе либо обнулите ссылки, либо лист имеет метод Remove() - удалите ссылки из первого листа.

Совсем коротко: Вы пишете именно про то, что вам нужно перенести "предметы", и вам не нужно создавать новые предметы. "Перенос" предметов - это перенос [копирование] ссылок из одного листа [инвентарь А] в другой лист [инвентарь Б]. Из первого листа [инвентарь А] не забудьте удалить ссылки на то, что вы перенесли во второй лист [инвентарь Б].

@InterceptorTSK Видимо я немного неправильно выразился, мне нужно один объект неопределённого типа (но мы знаем что он ребенок Item) разделить на 2 разных объекта (Но одного типа), с разными ссылками.

Объекты не бывают неопределённых типов, у любого объекта есть тип, иначе никак. Узнать тип объекта можно разными способами, и сравнить этот тип объекта, что бы понять например что вам нужно. Два разных объекта - это что за объекты? То что изначальный экземпляр объекта есть - это понятно, но на что нужно разделить этот изначальный экземпляр объекта?

Если вы хотите "размножить" [не разделить, а размножить] существующий объект на например два [т.е. сделать копию объекта], то это нужно использовать например копирование объекта, оно есть, бывает глубоким/не глубоким. Но в общем вам нужно взять существующий объект, узнать его тип, затем по этому типу создать новый объект такого же типа, и все поля [значения полей] скопировать в новосозданный объект.

И тут конечно же есть проблема, если поле объекта - это ссылка на иной объект, то придётся копировать и этот объект, на который ссылается поле объекта.

Посмотрите например вот здесь https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.22.php

Если вам надо предмет из одного List<Item> в другой List<Item> перенести, то логика довольно проста: 1. Находите сам объект любым удобным способом, например var item = inventory.Single(x=> x...); (x...) = ваше условие поиска. Далее делаете простое удаление и добавление inventory.Remove(item) и newInventory.Add(item), все, вы перенесли объект. Если "перенос" для вас, это изменение int count;, то также, ищите объект, но уже в двух инвентарях сразу, ну и делайте у одного -1, а у другого +1.

@EvgeniyZ автор вопроса хочет не это

@InterceptorTSK Неопределённого, в смысле мы точно не знаем какого типа он. У меня один абстрактный класс Item и различные дети от него, поэтому чтобы мне сделать клонирование / копирование, мне придется прописывать Copy для каждого класса-дитя. Хотелось бы, вот у нас есть переменная, получить её тип, и используя конструктор этого типа создать новую переменную

Так как вы хотите - можно, но не нужно. Автоматическое полное копирование объектов - существует. Но оно использует "тугие методы" отражения [рефлексии]. Для этого написаны сторонние библиотеки, они есть. Но в вашем случае это вряд ли приемлимо. А потому что - а зачем? Задайтесь вопросом - почему Майкрософт "по дифолту" не включил такие библиотеки в Дот.Нет? У вас пусть пять [пусть семь] производных типов, написать на них всё что нужно для клонирования [ручками написать] - не проблема. И для этого не нужно подтягивать тяжёлую артиллерию.

Или гуглите эти сторонние библиотеки, например как "C# object copy/clone library". Первое попавшееся - "Deep Cloner" какое то. На гит-хабе лежит.

@OkeJS Вы пишете: "мне придется прописывать Copy для каждого класса-дитя.". Так и есть. Но проблема ли это? Механизм копирования можно написать в самом классе и использовать интерфейсы. Это если "по фен-шую". А можно без этого) Ну т.е. совсем "втупую" создать тот же экземпляр объекта того же типа, из уже имеющегося объекта. Тут даже интерфейсы не нужны, и общие абстракции не нужны. В нижеприведённом коде нужно заполнить то, как у вас что копируется. Само копирование можно определить в общем методе, а не в самих конкретных классах. Иногда это очень удобно.

Как вариант, сделать у ваших классов метод клонирования, и пусть они сами создают свои копии.

Ещё актуально?.

В базовом классе Item создаем виртуальный метод makeCopy который должен возвращать объект-наследник от Item
В потомках перекрываем этот метод и создаем объект нужного типа. Копируем туда данные и возвращаем этот объект.
Все.
var ListA = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Item>(); // Items from
var ListB = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Item>(); // Items copy/clone to
ListA.Add(new Item());
ListA.Add(new Item());
ListA.Add(new UsableItem());
ListA.Add(new UsableItem());
ListA.Add(new ComponentItem());
ListA.Add(new ComponentItem());

for (int i = 0; i < ListA.Count; i++)
{
    Item item = ListA[i];
    ListB.Add(item.makeCopy());
}


    var ListA = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Item>(); // Items from
    var ListB = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Item>(); // Items copy/clone to
    ListA.Add(new Item());
    ListA.Add(new Item());
    ListA.Add(new UsableItem());
    ListA.Add(new UsableItem());
    ListA.Add(new ComponentItem());
    ListA.Add(new ComponentItem());

    for (int i = 0; i < ListA.Count; i++)
    {
        Item item = ListA[i];
        System.Type itemType = item.GetType();

        //System.Console.WriteLine(itemType); // All types here

        if (itemType == typeof(Item))
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Create and copy/clone Item");

            // New reference[newItem] and new object
            Item newItem = new Item();

            // Clone/copy old item to new()

            // Add reference[newItem] to ListB
            ListB.Add(newItem);
        }
        else if (itemType == typeof(UsableItem))
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Create and copy/clone UsableItem");

            // New reference[newUsableItem] and new object
            UsableItem newUsableItem = new UsableItem();

            // Clone/copy old item to new()

            // Add reference[newUsableItem] to ListB
            ListB.Add(newUsableItem);
        }
        else if (itemType == typeof(ComponentItem))
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Create and copy/clone ComponentItem");

            // New reference[newComponentItem] and new object
            ComponentItem newComponentItem = new ComponentItem();

            // Clone/copy old item to new()

            // Add reference[newComponentItem] to ListB
            ListB.Add(newComponentItem);
        }
        else
            throw new System.NotSupportedException(itemType.ToString());
    }


ужасное решение с точки зрения ООП

А тут нужно ооп? Причём здесь вообще ооп? Для ооп нужно вкарячивать кучу методов [интерфейстых методов] в классы Items, либо компилятор их вкарячит, если это какая то автоматизация. И главный вызывающий метод у вас это makeCopy() будет массово вызывать методы от методов [от методов ...] сообразно тому как определяется копирование каждого класса. И всё это погрязнет в массовой типизации [проверке типов], и в массовом вызове методов.

Вы проблем не решаете. Если Item не ваш [или ваш] - но вы по какой то причине не можете вкарячить собственные методы копирования - чего делать? Как этим всем управлять? В общем смысле. Есть три класса, они копируются как то, вы это всё растащите по трём разным файлам? Третье - если копирование разное? В одной ситуации - одно, в другой ситуации - другое. Четвёртое - само копирование как абстракция - чему должно принадлежать? Логике ооп? Или может оно должно принадлежать самому листу? Логика принадлежит листу - пусть лист и копирует, свойство "копировать" - это свойство листа, а не item-ов.

У вас логика ооп может и есть, а как таковой логики - нет. И чего вам даёт логика ооп, если она противоречит логике вменяемых абстракций?

Идём далее, вот вы значит определите копирование в самих классах. И зачем? Вы наплодите ссылок в этих классах. Выше написано, что вы будете массово вызывать методы от методов [от методов] этих самых классов. И это пол-беды. Вы ссылки раскидаете по памяти - вот беда. А нужно сложить все ссылки - локально. Т.е. должен быть общий метод копирования, где все временные ссылки тоже в одном месте. Тогда у коллектора мозги не свернутся, отслеживая существование ссылок.

А суть следующая: вы там "что то" программируете, но зачем вы это программируете - вы не знаете. И как это работает - вы тоже не знаете. Но критики - почему то вагон. А теперь объяснитесь, хотя бы как то. Если конечно сможете.


в тегах вопроса есть тег "ооп". 2. про методы методов это Вы знатно накрутили... : ) 3. Проверки типов при реализации через перекрытие виртуальных методов происходит на этапе компиляции. В отличии от предложенного Вами решения. Свое решение я привел в своем ответе на этот вопрос


@Андрей Туманов вы определяете метод копирования объекта в самом объекте. Через метод. Наследуя объекты - вы будете дёргать метод от метода [от метода ...] - зависит от глубины наследования. Так называемая проверка типов - вообще не существует. У объекта всегда вызывается callvirt таблица методов - вы эту таблицу и дёргаете массово. Обращаетесь к этим таблицам миллион раз, если копируете миллион объектов. Потому что обращаетесь к методам объекта. А оно точно нужно? Для копирования объекта подавляюще часто хватает конструктора. Если объект прост - то зачем усложнять копирование?

Самого главного вы не решили - что делать с миллионом временных ссылок, которые вы наплодите зачем то. "Проверки типов при реализации через перекрытие виртуальных методов происходит на этапе компиляции." - это вам кто написал? Очередной рихтер? А вам рихтер не написал, что на самом деле делает рантайм с уже скомпилированным так называемым кодом? Ну конечно же нет, рихтеру это зачем? Он и сам не знает что происходит.

"В отличии от предложенного Вами решения." - это не решение, что такое решение - я не знаю. Паттерны какие то, решения какие то, что это такое - мне не известно. Рантайм работает так, как он работает. Коллектор работает ровно так, как он работает. Пейсать некие розовые абстракции в вакууме можно, но это всё банально втыкает палки в колёса рантайму. И всё. Ну втыкайте палки в колёса - вы этим и занимаетесь. Я не против. Продолжайте.
